# iPhone pathForResource vs bundlePath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, relative-path, nsbundle

I want to use pathForResource, but it doesn't look like it will create the path if one doesn't exist.  Therefore I'm trying to create one manually by doing the following:

```
 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath],@"myFileName"];
```

I'm creating files dynamically, so I need to access them after I have `Build and Run` the application.  But it puts the project in a unique id folder so the path comes out to something like:

```
/Users/RyanJM/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/80986747-37FD-49F3-9BA8-41A42AF7A4CB/MyApp.app/myFileName.plist
```

But that unique id changes every time I do a build. What is the proper way to create a path that I can get to every time (even in the Simulator)?

Thanks.

Update: edited the question, hopefully to help anyone who comes across it in the future.

Update: IWasRobbed answered the proper way to get create a path URL.  But the the best answer I've been able to find is from [Brad Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046893/keep-app-directory-the-same-when-building-for-iphone-simulator).  Though, I do wish there was a cleaner way.

Comment: Before builds or after builds?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.  I need to access the same path between builds (when testing the program out in the simulator).

Comment: He's creating them dynamically apparently so he needs access to them after builds (i.e. once the program is running, it had no prior knowledge of the file being in the bundle) even though he phrases it differently.

Comment: IWasRobbed, thanks for rewording it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you phrased your question, this is how you read a plist that has been included in the bundle before build:

```
NSString *propertyListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:SomeString ofType:@"plist"];
```

If you want to access the directories that each app has as a unique storage area for a file that you create AFTER build, you use this:

```
#define kFilename   @”data.plist”

- (NSString *)dataFilePath { 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}
```

Then you can check for it and do some data handling here:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath]; 

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
// do something with data here
}
```

You would save yourself a lot of trouble if you bought/read `Beginning iPhone 3 Development` specifically chapter 11 where he goes over data persistence (which is where this example came from).  It's a great book.

Comment: But pathForResource returns nil if the resource doesn't exist.  So how do you create the path for a new resource?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  And I will have to check that book out.

Comment: It still creates a unique path for the simulator.  Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why it does that on the simulator (might have something to do with some unique key it uses), but know that it gives a consistent path on the device