# Specify build folder for iphone application

Tags: iphone, build-settings, directory-structure

I've written an app that uses some of the user's camera roll images, and while it does so it stores them in the application root directory. The problem I have is that whenever I re-compile my application it changes the folder to which the application is installed.
Is there any way I can specify which folder it should build to, so that any path information stored during it's last run will still be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is something you can stop Xcode from doing unfortunately. It should be copying the data from the old location to the new one but sometimes that just doesn't happen.

The answer suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046893/keep-app-directory-the-same-when-building-for-iphone-simulator) looks like the solution you are after.

Comment: Thank you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271577/how-to-keep-the-iphone-simulator-application-directory-be-the-same-when-run-it-ev linked from the question you pointed me to was actually more useful.